# Alternative to SUMPRODUCT

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to compute two columns from another excel sheet. Let's say the first sheet is RAW DATA with first column is Date, second is Total, third is Duration and the last one is my counter (to check duplicates). Before I can compute for the Total Duration which should be placed in TALLY SHEET, it has to meet the following criteria: Date has to be equal to the date in the TALLY SHEET and the counter column has to be equal to 1.

The TALLY SHEET has the following columns (in order): Date and Total Duration.

In my Total Duration column in TALLY SHEET, I use the formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS('RAW DATA'!B:B,'RAW DATA'!A:A,A2,'RAW DATA'!D:D,1),
            SUMIFS('RAW DATA'!C:C,'RAW DATA'!A:A,A2,'RAW DATA'!D:D,1))
/SUMIFS('RAW DATA'!B:B,'RAW DATA'!A:A,A2,'RAW DATA'!D:D,1))
```

However that formula only sums the duration and doesn't execute the `SUMPRODUCT()` function. If I do it in the RAW DATA sheet with `=SUMPRODUCT(B:B,C:C)/SUM(B:B)` it works.

Comment: When you post a question, please remember to copy the *exact* formula you are using from your worksheet and paste in it **without modifying it**. That way we can be sure we are all on the same page. (The formula in your question has an extra `)` at the end, so it couldn't have come as is from a worksheet cell.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the correct way to modify the formula `=SUMPRODUCT(B:B,C:C)/SUM(B:B)` to check for the specified conditions.

Your formula won't produce the expected cross product as you are summing inside the `SUMPRODUCT()`.

`SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(«Total»),SUMIFS(«Duration»)/SUMIFS(«Total»)` is the same as `SUMIFS(«Total»)*SUMIFS(«Duration»)/SUMIFS(«Total»)` which is, of course the same as `SUMIFS(«Duration»)`

You need to use a different style of formula, one that produces *arrays* inside the `SUMPRODUCT()`. The following style is suitable provided there are ***only*** number-convertible values in columns `B` and `C`. (An empty string returned by a formula is not number-convertible. Nor are errors.)

Enter this formula in `B2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down into the rest of the column:

```dart
=SUMPRODUCT('RAW DATA'!$B$2:$B$10*('RAW DATA'!$A$2:$A$10=A2)*('RAW DATA'!$D$2:$D$10=1),
            'RAW DATA'!$C$2:$C$10*('RAW DATA'!$A$2:$A$10=A2)*('RAW DATA'!$D$2:$D$10=1))
/SUMIFS('RAW DATA'!B:B,'RAW DATA'!A:A,A2,'RAW DATA'!D:D,1)
```

Note that for this style of formula, it is *not* recommended to use entire columns inside the `SUMPRODUCT()`, as it slows down the formula execution a *lot*.

Just remember to replace the ranges with ones of the appropriate number of rows, or make them dynamic so they automatically adjust according to the data present.

**Explanation:**

The `('RAW DATA'!$A$2:$A$10=A2)` part checks if the date matches and the `('RAW DATA'!$D$2:$D$10=1)` part checks if the counter equals `1`.

When these arrays are multiplied together, `TRUE` becomes a `1` and `FALSE` a `0`. So the result is `1` only if both are true.

Multiplying by `'RAW DATA'!$B$2:$B$10` (or `'RAW DATA'!$C$2:$C$10`) results in the appropriate total (or duration) value, if and only if the date matches and the counter is a `1`.

The `SUMPRODUCT()` function cross multiplies the two arrays, and *then* sums them.

Of course, the above formula can be refactored/simplified to the following, as the conditions checked for are the same for both the total and duration:

```dart
=SUMPRODUCT('RAW DATA'!$B$2:$B$10*'RAW DATA'!$C$2:$C$10*('RAW DATA'!$A$2:$A$10=A2)*('RAW DATA'!$D$2:$D$10=1))
/SUMIFS('RAW DATA'!B:B,'RAW DATA'!A:A,A2,'RAW DATA'!D:D,1)
```

EDIT:

If the values in columns `B` and `C` are generated by formulas and the formulas can return empty strings, when this happens the formula above will result in a `#VALUE!` error. The following will fix this by treating the empty strings as zeroes:

```dart
=SUMPRODUCT(("0"&'RAW DATA'!$B$2:$B$10)*("0"&'RAW DATA'!$C$2:$C$10)*('RAW DATA'!$A$2:$A$10=A2)*('RAW DATA'!$D$2:$D$10=1))
/SUMIFS('RAW DATA'!B:B,'RAW DATA'!A:A,A2,'RAW DATA'!D:D,1)
```

---

An alternative formula can be constructed using `SUM()` and `IF()`.

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in `B2` and copy-paste/fill-down into the rest of the column (don't forget to remove the `{` and `}`):

```dart
{=SUM(IF(('RAW DATA'!$A$2:$A$10=A2)*('RAW DATA'!$D$2:$D$10=1),'RAW DATA'!$B$2:$B$10*'RAW DATA'!$C$2:$C$10,0))
/SUMIFS('RAW DATA'!B:B,'RAW DATA'!A:A,A2,'RAW DATA'!D:D,1)}
```

Note that `SUM` can be replaced with `SUMPRODUCT` and the formula will work just the same.

EDIT:

The same issue with empty strings in the `B` and `C` columns as above also applies for this formula. The following fixes this:

```dart
=SUM(IF(('RAW DATA'!$A$2:$A$10=A2)*('RAW DATA'!$D$2:$D$10=1),("0"&'RAW DATA'!$B$2:$B$10)*("0"&'RAW DATA'!$C$2:$C$10),0))
/SUMIFS('RAW DATA'!B:B,'RAW DATA'!A:A,A2,'RAW DATA'!D:D,1)
```

Comment: I'm getting #VALUE! error

Comment: @Astrid22 You will get that if there are non-number convertible text values in columns `B` or `C` (including an empty looking cell containing just spaces). Try the formula on a smaller range of clean data as a test. If you can't solve the issue, please add a sample of your data **as text** to your question. (A screenshot would be nice too ;-) )

Comment: Hi, sorry I can't post a screenshot yet as my computer is playing up. But I'll do my best. Anyway going back, it seems that I'm having issues with the SUMPRODUCT part. Is it really supposed to have a part like this where the other one is not enclosed in parenthesis with criteria =SUMPRODUCT('RAW DATA'!B2:B10*('RAW DATA'!A2:A10=A2)?

Comment: @Astrid22 Sorry about my mistake. You are correct (in your original comment) in that the two formula are not equivalent. However, the correct equivalent of `=SUMPRODUCT(B:B,C:C)/SUM(B:B)` is `=SUMPRODUCT('RAW DATA'!B2:B10*'RAW DATA'!C2:C10)/SUM(B:B)`. I should have said "the correct way to modify the formula to check for the specified conditions is". And yes, the part not enclosed in brackets is supposed to be there. The criteria parts are the "selectors" whilst the part not in brackets is the "value". Note that the value must be a "number" for this style of formula. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79643/discussion-between-astrid-22-and-robincts).